# Differences between Form and Adapter Based Authentication in Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

Can you please let me know the differences between Form and Adapter Based Authentication. I've gone through the pdf provided by IBM but was not able to find actual difference.

Certain queries comes into my mind is:

- How validation occurs? and comparison of username and password from server with entered `j_username` and `j_password`.

Right now for example it's accepting any combination of username and password.

Since they are using `requrl = /j_security_check`

- How to validate username and password with server?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Form and Adapter Based Authentication is that Form Based Authentication is using MobileFirst internal classes and methods, and When using Adapter Based Authentication you are responsible for the authentication procedures (which should be located inside an adapter) - you only declare in the securityTest what procedures to use for login and logout.
If you want to use Form-Based Authentication with username and password you can use Single Identity login module. 
More information about Single Identity login module can be found here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_single_identity_login_module.html